# I swapped to cloudflare for free SSL certs, how do I SSH?

Tags: ssh

I am a novice, just running a personal web server for the first time using word press. Main goal just doing it as a hobby and learning the correct way to secure things.

Ubuntu 22.10

I've got a couple of questions about SSH.

I set up a SSL cert through Cloudflare which is now using their name servers and due to this my domain names IP is pointed at them. I know I can SSH directly to my machine via IP but it was nice typing the domain name to reach the same IP, which I guess you could say is now more secure anyway, even if it is just 'security by obscurity' which isn't really that good in the cyber security world.

But I want to know if there something I can do to fix this? Perhaps on Cloudflares end there's settings I can do to reroute the SSH protocol to the right IP.

<strike>My other questions are:</strike>

- what's some things I should be doing with SSH to make it more secure? E.G. Changing the default port?
- What is the difference between SSH and SSHD, I notice my server has configs for both yet systemctl status mentions ssh is running and sshd.service could not be found.

Appreciate the responses, cheers for your time!

EDIT:
Striked out additional questions.
Found my answer with their documentation: https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/policies/filtering/network-policies/ssh-logging/

Comment: Does Cloudflare have any config and or usage support.

Comment: @David

Cloudflare does have quite the elaborate control panel... I'm also not paying for anything from them it was just a way to get a free SSL cert set up going.
Suppose I could try their support to see what they say. Since I had other questions I figured I'd ask here too.

Comment: Ssh is for client side and sshd is for server side. Obviously Linux systems generally act as both SSH servers and SSH clients. You should modify the ssh config in the system that is used for client and sshd config for the system that is used as server in your case.

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Apologies - I quickly realised how inconvenient it was to ask multiple questions, seeing as this website has a Question->Answer format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudflare SSH using domain name requires you to set up proxy for it. Their documentation is [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/policies/filtering/network-policies/ssh-logging/).

Thanks @FedKad for explaining to me that SSH config is client related and SSHD config is for server side which is what I need to edit to change default listening port.